# How to reproduce this Feynman diagram using tikz-feynman?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-feynman

I want to reproduce the following Feynman diagram
[image]

and my attempt at it yields something like this

[image]

Notice that the loop doesn't look circular and it would be nice to have those bent arrows as well. Here's my code (I'm using `tikz-feynman` with LuaLaTeX)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a);
            \node[rectangle, draw, minimum size=0.075cm,label=-120:\(F_2\)] (b) at (1.5,0);
            \node[dot, label=below:\(P_{lin}\)] (c) at (2.5,1);
            \node[dot, label=above:\(P_{lin}\)] (d) at (2.5,-1);
            \node[rectangle, draw, minimum size=0.075cm,label=-60:\(F_2\)] (e) at (3.5,0);
            \vertex [right=1.5cm of e] (f);
            \diagram*{(b) -- [fermion] (a),
            (b) -- [fermion, quarter left] (c),
            (e) -- [fermion, quarter right] (c),
            (e) -- [fermion, quarter left] (d),
            (b) -- [fermion, quarter right] (d),
            (e) -- [fermion] (f)};
        \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please suggest a way to reproduce the Feynman diagram using `tikz-feynman` (in combination with `tikz`, if required).

Comment: Are you using `tikz-feynman` with LuaLaTeX? (Doesn't look like it but just to be sure …)

Comment: Please stop and change your habbit right away: code you post needs to start with `\documentclass`, end with `\end{document}` and must compile. Doing so avoids a handful of questions right away. // Just to illustrate the consequence of such little care: I was about to try your code, but ... no longer ...

Comment: Both of you are correct. Extremely sorry for my sloppy writing. I've modified my question. I hope now you have the necessary details to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this simple case, it's easy to cheat:

- Draw a circle.
- Place the nodes on the circle.
  Make the rectangles use `fill = white`.
- Add the bended arrows without drawing the path again ([`tips`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#pgf/tips)).

Unfortunately, the `fermion` arrows are actually `isosceles triangle` nodes, so it's going to need a bit investing if we can make the arrow tips (for which the `bending` library makes it very easy to get bended forms of it) the same size.

(Nodes can be transformed nonlinear which is the kind of transformation applied for the bending of arrows but it's not trivial to set up.)

I also don't want to mess around with the right positioning which is why I've used the `ext.arrows` library from my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext) for the `Centered Triangle` arrow tip.

LuaLaTeX which `tikz-feynman` is made for would allow us to use the [`necklace routing`](https://tikz.dev/gd-edge-routing#pgf.necklace:routing) for the circular edges …

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{warn luatex=false}
\usetikzlibrary{bending, ext.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}[/tikz/rect/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=.075cm, fill=white}]
\vertex (a);
\draw (2.5,0) coordinate (center) circle[radius=1];
\foreach \sa in {90, -90}
  \foreach \da in {45, -45}
    \path[-{Centered Triangle[scale length=2, bend]}, tips]
      ([shift=(center)]\sa:1) arc[start angle=\sa, delta angle=\da, radius=1];
\node[rect, label= -120:\(F_2\)             ] (b) at (1.5, 0);
\node[dot,  label=below:\(P_{\mathrm{lin}}\)] (c) at (2.5, 1);
\node[dot,  label=above:\(P_{\mathrm{lin}}\)] (d) at (2.5,-1);
\node[rect, label=  -60:\(F_2\)             ] (e) at (3.5, 0);
\vertex [right=1.5cm of e] (f);
\diagram*{
  (b) -- [fermion] (a),
  (e) -- [fermion] (f)
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce circular loop with bent arrows using something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432103/hartree-diagram-with-tikz-feynman-just-a-circle-as-propagator)?@Qrrbrbirlbel